# How to show an UIActivityindicator in UICollectionview customcell untill the image downloads at server side?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiactivityindicatorview

Can Any one help me how to show the activity indicator until the image for UICollection cell downloads at back end.

In my code the activity indicator is show only for last cell..Don't know where I m making the mistake

Here is my code:

```
 - (collectionCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self.menuCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"collectionCell"
bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

collectionCell= [menuCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" 
                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

MenuItems *item=[itemsfinal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSMutableString *str   = [NSMutableString  stringWithFormat:@"%@", item.itemImage];

NSLog(@" url %@",str);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self loadImage:str]];

if(image !=nil){
    collectionCell.menuRecipeImage.image = image;

    collectionCell.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;

    [collectionCell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

}else{
    collectionCell.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;

    [collectionCell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    collectionCell.menuRecipeImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menudefualt.png"];
}

return collectionCell;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you should set up your activity indicator. Then start loading your image for the cell in the background. When the image  have loaded apply it to the cell on the main thread.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    __block UICollectionViewCell* cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                                                       forIndexPath: indexPath];

    // Placeholder text --
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.text = @"Downloading...";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    // Load image in background  --
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/img/img%02lu.png", (long unsigned)indexPath.row]];

        // Load and decode image --
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        // Apply image on the main thread --
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
        });
    });

    return cell;

}
```

The example in action...

[image: Placeholder text being replaced with images as they load]

Comment: Thank you Niels.. This is really nice for loading images..

Niels Castle

Answer (score 1):

One thing about Niels example is that this may cause an incorrect image to be set for a cell, if the cell is re-used before the image is completely loaded (eg. if you're scrolling quickly). So you need to keep a map of what URL should be set for each cell, so roughly modifying Niels' example above:

```
@property NSDictionary *cellMap;

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    __block UICollectionViewCell* cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"
                                                                       forIndexPath: indexPath];

    // Placeholder text --
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.text = @"Downloading...";
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/img/img%02lu.png", (long unsigned)indexPath.row]];
    [cellMap setObject:url forKey:cell];

    // Load image in background  --
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

        // Load and decode image --
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        // Apply image on the main thread --
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSURL *cellUrl = [cellMap objectForKey:cell];
            if (cellUrl == url) {
                // Only set the image if the url is still the same for this cell
                UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
                [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
            }
        });
    });

    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
   return 1;
  } 

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return _items.count;
  }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   ImageFilterCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ImageFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.lblEffectName.text = [_itemsName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.imgLoader.hidden = NO;
   cell.imgFilter.image = nil;

   NSString *effectName = _items[indexPath.row];
   if([effectName isEqualToString:@"Original"]){
      cell.imgLoader.hidden = YES;
      cell.imgFilter.image = _imgThumb;
   }
   else {
     UIImage *filteredImage = [_filteredImages objectForKey:effectName];
     if(filteredImage){
         cell.imgLoader.hidden = YES;
         cell.imgFilter.image = filteredImage;
     } else {
         __weak ImageFilterCell *weakCell = cell;

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
             [self getFilteredImageForEffect:effectName forImage:_imgThumb completionBlock:^(UIImage *image) {
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     weakCell.imgLoader.hidden = YES;
                     weakCell.imgFilter.image = image;
                     [_filteredImages setObject:image forKey:effectName];
                 });
            }];
         });
     }
 }
 if(_checkedIndexPath==indexPath.row)
     cell.highlighted = YES;
 else
     cell.highlighted = NO;

 return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if(_checkedIndexPath != indexPath.row && indexPath.row!=0){
     _checkedIndexPath = indexPath.row;
     NSString *effectName = _items[indexPath.row];
     if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showIndicator)]){
         [_delegate showIndicator];
     }
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         [self getFilteredImageForEffect:effectName forImage:_orgImage completionBlock:^(UIImage *image) {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(filterImageView:filteredImage:)]){
                     [self.delegate filterImageView:self filteredImage:image];
                 }
             });
         }];
     });
  } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      _checkedIndexPath = 0;
      if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(filterImageView:filteredImage:)]){
         [self.delegate filterImageView:self filteredImage:_orgImage];
     }
 }
 [_collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: please suggest me any library for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async image load. It can be done with [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html)

```
//First start your activityIndicator
collectionCell.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
[collectionCell.activityIndicator startAnimating];

//Then using GCD load your image on secondary thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{  
 //Here your image loading from url
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self loadImage:str]];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //This block (Main thread) waits until your image will be downloaded
  //(Note that all operation with views must be executed on a main thread)
  //Then loading is done just set your image and stop activityIndicator
   collectionCell.menuRecipeImage.image = image;
   collectionCell.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
   [collectionCell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
  });
});
```